# ShowEditor and Rich Text Field is not displaying in sitecore 7.1 application

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

We have migrated an application from sitecore 6.2 to sitecore 7.1.

We are facing an issue related to Rich Text Field which is not showing up when I open a content item. The Show Editor is also not popping up the Rich Text Editor for editing.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: What was your upgrade path, did you upgrade directly from 6.2 to 7.1, or did you follow or the intermediate steps as well?

Comment: It was incremental upgrade. step by step

Answer (score 2):

When I am facing this kind of issues after upgrading I tend to put tickets @ support.sitecore.net and dig some deeper into it myself. What I normally do is get a clean web.config + complete fresh bin folder of the Sitecore version I've upgraded to. Also I make sure that I grab the /sitecore folder with it.

Then I will compare the fresh bin with the solution bin and replace any assemblies that are not the same. From there I will also do a folder compare (using beyond compare or any other good compare tool) to make sure I got all the necessary files from there. Also I make sure that I look for any posts on the Sitecore forum containing the same problems. Don't forget to view your logs, as they will sometime help you find your problem quicker.